# What 80s/90s cartoon had a girl with a koala, and a father trapped in a bubble in another world?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, space-exploration

All I remember are very vague details, probably 25 years ago or so.

A young girl (blonde?) is in search of her father who seems to be lost in another world of sorts. I believe he is in a bubble, and spoke to her sometimes but you could only see his silhouette through the shape of his bubble...? I don't know if he was lost between worlds or what. She couldn't ever get to him.

If I'm not mixing cartoons up, she had a koala that hung out in the tree outside her window. Graphics were realistic for that time period.

I'd love to know if this sounds familiar to anyone!

Comment: “Graphics were realistic for that time period.” — Was it computer-generated?

Comment: It was actually her _grandfather_ who had been lost in the other world, Koala-Ola Land. Blinky looked like a normal stuffed animal when he slept until  Sandy, his human friend, nuzzled his nose. His sister Pinky had a few more magical powers than he did, including jumping between dimensions. Sandy's grandfather was an explorer who found the portal between the dimensions, which essentially started the story.

Answer (score 7):

Could it be [Noozles?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noozles) It's about a girl exploring an alternate dimension with her magic koala friends in search of her father (whose own father is trapped in a giant crystal sphere); it used to show on Nickelodeon back in the late 80's.

[image]